# Difference between scipy.ndimage.gaussian_gradient_magnitude & gaussian_filter function

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy

Anyone know what's the difference between `scipy.ndimage.gaussian_gradient_magnitude` [[1]](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.gaussian_gradient_magnitude.html) and `scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter`[[2]](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter.html) function?

I imagine that `gaussian_gradient_magnitude(img, 1)` & `gaussian_filter(img, sigma= 1, order = 1)` should return same results, but this is just not the case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`scipy.ndimage.gaussian_gradient_magnitude` computes the magnitude of the [gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient), which is the vector containing the [partial derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative) along each axis. `scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter` can compute those partial derivatives.

For a 2D image (`img` is a 2D NumPy array),

```
gm = scipy.ndimage.gaussian_gradient_magnitude(img, 1)
```

is the same as

```
dx = scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter(img, sigma= 1, order = (0,1))
dy = scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter(img, sigma= 1, order = (1,0))
gm = numpy.sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2)
```

But note that both alternatives above only produce correct results if the array is a floating-point type (ndimage fails to properly promote the type of the output array to contain the values it computes; in particular, derivatives can have negative values, so the partial derivative images must be of a signed type to make sense).

Comment: Thanks for the note about the type. Was getting some really weird results., and didn't understand why.